# Deleting Custom List view item android without remove method

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom list view whose parent class is Base Adapter. Now i need to delete its menu item .i searched for it and  most of the tutorial says to use "remove"  method and will be done.But actually in all tutorials they extend their class from Array-adapter.Now problem in my case is i didn't find the remove method in Base Adapter class to use it . so how i can remove my list view item in this case ?.

Comment: you can just create a method named remove, where you delete the item from list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a remove in a `BaseAdapter`, because `ArrayAdapter` is already an `Array` so..

What you can do is remove the item from the `ArrayList<>` and then set it again for the `adapter`, and after that call `notifyDataSetChanged()`,

have a setData(ArrayList) in your adapter so you don't have to instantiate a new one. i.e.

```
setData(ArrayList list) {
   this.list = list;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

hope this helps